# Convert ps/2 to usb using ttl to usb converter

Tags: usb, ttl, conversion, ps2

I have an old keyboard that has ps/2 interface. I have a ttl(V G tx rx) to usb converter too. Can i use this converter to connecting my keyboard to  USB  port?
What about RS232/RS485 to USB converter? Can i use that to this convertion and connection?

Comment: Wow! Very harsh and abrupt! It’s no wonder Donald Trump is president. When smart people behave this way, it only drives people to become anti-intellectual. He couldn’t frame his question in the proper context because he doesn’t know enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a ttl(V G tx rx) to usb converter too. Can i use this converter to connecting my keyboard to USB port?

No.

> What about RS232/RS485 to USB converter? Can i use that to this convertion and connection?

No.

The [PS/2 keyboard interface](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/) is different to those on the converters / adapters you mentioned. However there are [commercially-available PS/2 to USB converters available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port#Conversion_between_PS.2F2_and_USB), if that is what you want to do.

Here is an example of one of those commercially-available converters from a randomly-picked supplier's website, to give you an idea of what they can look like:

[image: example random photo of PS/2 keyboard & mouse to USB host converter]
<sup>[Source](http://www.cables2u.co.uk/keyboard-mouse-adapter-p-45.html)</sup>

Or, if you wanted to start a project, you could design your own converter using an MCU with a USB interface. This will be much easier if you choose an MCU where there are USB HID-class examples already available.

Comment: Gee. Thanks for being a hero to that poor soul who got a pounding from the SO gestapo.